# can someone help me find out how to check if numbers in this list are divisible by 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How am i able to check as to whether the numbers in my_randoms are divisible by 3 
and i there is any way to append these  items to the list called l.

This code already prints 30 random numbers and  i have tried different methods such as this :

```
n % 3 == 0
```

It would not work and kept crashing so i am struggling

```
import random
my_randoms = random.sample(range(30), 30)
print(my_randoms)

l = []
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [n for n in my_randoms if not n%3]
[27, 9, 24, 6, 18, 3, 12, 21, 15, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if it is divisible with

```
n % 3 == 0
```

and append the divisible ones like this:

```
import random

l = []
my_randoms = random.sample(range(30), 30)
print(my_randoms)
for number in myrandoms:
    if number%3 == 0:
        l.append(number)
print(l)
```

Comment: You could use a list comprehension too: `l = [number for number in my_randoms if number%3 == 0]`